How to Automate the Conversion of Log Analytics Query Alerts to Application Insights Queries?
I'm working with Azure Monitor and have several alert rules defined using Log Analytics queries. I want to create equivalent alert rules in Application Insights using these queries, but I've noticed that the table names and some field names differ between Log Analytics and Application Insights.
For example, in Log Analytics, I use the Heartbeat table with a query like this:
Heartbeat
| where TimeGenerated > ago(5m)
| summarize count() by Computer

I want to convert any log analytic query rules to Application Insights query that would look like this:
availabilityResults
| where timestamp > ago(5m)
| summarize count() by cloud_RoleInstance

Is there an automated way or a tool/script that can help convert Log Analytics-based Kusto queries to Application Insights queries, considering the differences in tables and fields? I am looking for a solution that could be integrated into a CI/CD pipeline or used with Azure Functions or Logic Apps for automation purposes.
Any advice or examples would be greatly appreciated!


Since you're asking for advice, here is mine: don't bother writing the queries based on App Insights and continue using Log analytics queries. The storage backend of App Insights is Log analytics anyway.

But Log analytic rules gives alert on exceptions or app dependency failures. But for complex apps, again we have to analyze the traces in appinsight, which is again  requires another level of skillset for developers to understand the actual event or root cases from the application traces which is causing the alert triggering.

I might not understand it correctly. Is this a one time action to convert Log Analytics queries to the App Insights equivalent? I very much doubt there is a tool for that but when you do have the query a couple of text replacement command should do the trick.

But for the developers, does it matter whether they use the Log Analytics queries or App Insights queries? Both are based on the kusto language

using app insights queries though limits to just that single app insights resource.  you could have a ton of AI resources pointed at one logs workspace.  So it really depends on exactly the purpose.  also, Heartbeat is NOT availabilityResults.  see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource#table-structure for the mapping

The mapping of table names between LA and AI schemas is here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/convert-classic-resource#table-structure
It also has mappings of individual columns in each table as well.  in general it is a straight up 1:1 mapping; i don't know if any tools are available to automatically do it.
Querying through app insights and using the app insights schema will limit the data to that one app insights resource.
If you query through log analytics, the queries would also include results from ALL of the app insights resources that are linked to that workspace, so there you'd need additional parts of the query to filter to just the one app insights resource of interest.
